# CSS3 media not working

Tags: css, responsive-design

im trying to mimic example from this page http://learnlayout.com/media-queries.html ... it should do two things after resizing to small... 
1.) make LI elements INLINE.... this works for me 
2.) make NAV and sections ONE COLUMN... this doesnt work for me, see picture
[image]
here is code

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>vajcia</title>
</head>
<style>
body
{
    margin: 0 0;
}
#container
{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid green;
}
section
{
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
nav{

    background-color: red;
    width:200px;
    box-sizing:border-box;

    /*position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0px;*/
    float:left;
}
@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
    nav {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }
    section {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:599px) {
    nav li {
        display: inline;
    }
}

</style>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Taco</li>
                <li>Hours</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Hovno</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>      
        <section>
            The margin-left style for sections makes sure there is room for the nav. Otherwise the absolute and static elements would overlap
        </section>
        <section>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.
        </section>
        <section>
            Notice what happens when you resize your browser. It works nicely!
        </section>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: in the media query `@media screen and (min-width:600px)` try setting `nav { float:left; width:100%; }` and `section { float:left; width:100% }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wFtJ4/

```
body {
    margin: 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 120px;
}
#container {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid green;
}
section {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
nav {
    background-color: red;
    width:200px;
    box-sizing:border-box;

        /*position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0px;*/
    float:left;
}
@media screen and (max-width:599px) {
    nav li  { display: inline; }
    nav     { width: 100%; text-align: center; }
    section { margin-left: 0 !important; }
}
```

Your CSS is a bit haphazard, so I hope this shows you have to override some of your settings when you use `@media`queries ;)

Comment: uhm, im only following tutorial ;_; so is tutorial bad? its tutorial on css layout...

Comment: Tutorials are only written by humans - I have written tutorials which are incorrect before. My contribution to this post may be incorrect - everyone has an opinion, and in a free world, we have the ability to display it :) I just posted a fix, nothing more. My opinion is your CSS could be improved, that's all ;)

Comment: btw thanks, your answer was best, though Aurelien's wasnt that bad too

Comment: Thanks buddy! You can improve by making your CSS consistent - meaning you need to keep it structured & easy to read. When I looked at it, you had `<nav>` with other `<section>`s, and was quite confusing. Not to mention you were setting specific properties just to get it to work - it's all a learning curve, so you just need to keep writing more CSS :)

Comment: i dont understand how it should be right.... could you send me the improved code which you now mentioned how it could look better ?

Comment: Let me write a JSFiddle for you

Comment: could i ask one more thing?
after resizing windowto smaller, NAV's background-color doesnt always  cover whole NAV (whole height, only middle where is text)

i.e. 
1.)it paints whole NAV if i also adds border to normal NAV...
2.)it works if i add to normal NAV float:left (works also borderless)...
3.)but it doesnt cover whole NAV when i add float:left to MEDIA-MIN-WIDTH's NAV   ... so idk why it is so randomly working/not-working

Answer (score 1):

If you want one column for your nav (red ?) then you need to remove its float and its width.

```
@media screen and (max-width:599px) {
    nav li {
        display: inline;
    }
    nav {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: y this worked but i had to also nulify section's margin 
    section {
  width:100%;
  margin-left: 0; }
}

Comment: nav { width: 100%; } would be a bit better than nav{floaT:none,width:auto}
cause when i used first example, it coloured red whole NAV block... but when i used second example, it coloured only that part  inside NAV that was high as font-size(not whole NAV block)... so  idk if there's any other difference, or are both solutions correct?